# Magento 2 need help caching Varnish/Hitch/Redis

Tags: magento2

Im looking for a person that can help us find and fix the problem with our caching! Cause nobody can seem to find it.

**Setup:**

- Magento 2.2.4 (running on Apache server)
- Varnish 5.2.1 (in combination with Hitch to handle ssl)
- Redis 4.0.11

**Problem:**

When saving a product not only the related categories/products gets invalid but the whole varnish gets invalid?

We checked the varnish logs and we can see it banned the related categories and products but it's a mysterie why varnish his whole cache dissapears.

With more then 10.000 products and hourly product changes, this is not working at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how are you verifying the entire varnish cache is empty?

Comment: because every url on the front end is slow again ;)

Comment: I'm getting also similar issues, 
The console log says: 
`Mixed Content:  The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`